# Type Cast error from lambda to delegate

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I have been following this [Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/652556/Can-you-explain-Lazy-Loading) to implement **LazyLoading**, to initialize lazyObject with some value i am making a call to function with the help of **Lambda Expression.** But, i am getting **Conversion error and its saying its not delegate.** Below is the code:

```
private Lazy<t_user_audit> lazyList = null;
lazyList = new Lazy<t_user_audit>(() => new t_user_audit { client.GetAudit(10) });
```

I have searched the error on google, but its does not seems to be helpful and further i have seen this error first time in my life, so might be i am in need of coding help with proper syntax. So can anybody help me now.

```
public t_user_audit GetAudit(int id)
{
    return _work.GetGenericRepositoryFor<t_user_audit>().SingleOrDefault(p => p.CustomerId == id);
}
```

Now, as you can see i am working in layered architecture, so i won't be able for me to post the whole code and one more thing i am using `Entity Framework.`

After, using the above line, i get two errors:

**Error 17 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type**

And the second is:

**Error 18  Cannot initialize type 'BBTI.Entities.t_user_audit' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'**

Comment: What does `GetAudit` return?

Comment: Are you providing us with all the information we need here?  What does client.GetAudit(Int) return?

Comment: it will return an object with single record...

Comment: @HarshSharma, post the method signature please

Comment: It returns an Object or a List<t_User>?

Comment: If you could show a short but complete example of the problem, it would make it a *lot* easier to help you.

Comment: And in future, when you get an error, please include the *complete error message*. It's very hard to help you with so little information.

Comment: thanks @JonSkeet i will keep the advice in mind for future reference..

Comment: @iandotkelly Please have a look i have edited the question

Comment: @Andrei please have a look now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New answer with edited question**

The problem is that your lambda expression isn't valid - you're trying to use collection initializer syntax, but your type isn't a collection. So instead of this:

```
() => new t_user_audit { client.GetAudit(10) }
```

You want:

```
() => new List<t_user_audit> { client.GetAudit(10) }
```

**Original answer**

From the comments:

> "it will return an object with single record"

If you mean that `GetAudit` is declared to return a `t_User`, like this:

```
public t_User GetAudit(int something)
```

then that's the problem. To create a `Lazy<List<Foo>>` you need a delegate which will return a `List<Foo>`, not a single `Foo`. So this should work:

```
lazyList = new Lazy<List<t_User>>(() => new List<t_User> { client.GetAudit(10) });
```

Or you could make it a `Lazy<t_User>` instead, if you're only ever going to fetch a single use.

Another possibility (it's hard to tell as you haven't given enough information in the question) is that `GetAudit` returns something like an `IEnumerable<t_User>` instead of a `List<t_User>`. In that case, you would just need to create a list from the return value:

```
lazyList = new Lazy<List<t_User>>(() => client.GetAudit(10).ToList());
```

(I'd also *strongly* encourage you to start following .NET naming conventions, and ditch the `t_` prefix.)

Comment: "an object with single record" may just as easy be a list with one entry

Comment: @Andrei: *Maybe*. But I suspect not. We'll see :)

Comment: I suspect not too, (since he has an error), but that is also how I interpreted his comment.  Also the example returns a List<T>

Comment: @iandotkelly: Have edited my answer to be more circumspect :)

Comment: @HarshSharma: Surprised by what? Nothing in my answer seems particularly shocking...

Comment: No i mean, getting an answer from you i surprised, i mean i got a reply from person who give 500+ correct answer in 1 month :)

Comment: your `lazyList = new Lazy<List<t_User>>(() => client.GetAudit(10).ToList());` this line of code seems to be working thanks for your help, but i was not able to figure it out what wrong with this code line `lazyList = new Lazy<List<t_User>>(() => new List<t_User> { client.GetAudit(10) });`, its still showing me the same error.

Comment: @HarshSharma: Well you left us guessing, having given us neither the signature of `GetAudit` nor the exact error message. In future, please provide more information in the question - read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: @JonSkeet please have a look on it i have updated the question.

Comment: @HarshSharma: Well based on that edit it, I wouldn't expect the `ToList` version to work, but I *would* expect the `new List<...> { ... }` version to work. You still haven't posted the exact error message, either.

Comment: i think i have created a whole mess, let me edit my question again from scratch

Comment: @HarshSharma: See my edit. And you should still fix your type names to follow .NET conventions.